# Supporting RTL on old layouts which are designed manually for RTL

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, right-to-left

I use `Android Studio 3.5.2`.

In a very old project witch its `targetSdkVersion` is `14` (it is not updated for near 6 years) and was designed for devices with API lower than 17 and users that use right-to-left (`RTL`) scripts I have large number of `.xml` layout files (more than 80 files) which have a problem:

As application is old and for RTL scripts, horizontal order of elements are `mirrored`manually so they were appearing with RTL direction. That was good for that time; but now I want to publish an updated version of that. Also I want to use benefits of RTL API of Android. The problem occurs after changing `targetSdkVersion` to `17` or higher: [layout mirroring](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#SupportLayoutMirroring) will cause wrong direction of elements of old layouts.

What I thought about them for solving that problem are:

- Using `Add Right-to-Left (RTL) Support ...` of Android Studio does not solve the problem, because layout files are initially designed for RTL.
- I can force application to be LTR, but I guess it will *inactive* supporting RTL. *Is it true*?
- Also I can redesign all old layout files

It seems that only third option can solve the problem; but it is a very time consuming task. Is there any other way for solving that problem?

Comment: My feeling is option 3 is the safest to get things right. It probably won't take as long as you think once you get going - I've had to do this a fair amount recently myself. `ConstraintLayout` will be your friend here.

Comment: If I were in your place I would go with option 3. Why because it's the most clean way of doing it. I have gone through 1 and having AS help me but trust me you don't want to go that road. Like @RichardLeMesurier said with the use of constraintLayout you will save alot of time and also in this way you will be able to remove alot of old code too.

Comment: Further to ^^^, should have mentioned to keep your existing layouts for older devices that only support `left` and `right` instead of the `start` and `end` properties needed for easy RTL.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Thank you for your time. I thought it must be an old popular problem; because Android did not support RTL initially and there must be applications for RTL scripts before API 17 whiche were updated. So I expected there must be a solution (for example provided by Google) and I am looking for that.